# Save as bz2 format using JsonStorage with Apache Pig

Tags: apache-pig, bzip2

Is there any way to store data using bz2 with in JsonStorage?

I tried

```
STORE DATA INTO 'path_to_file.bz2’ USING JsonStorage();
```

But this is not successful.

I can do this with PigStorage, but it separates the field using a character delimiter and not in json.

Answer (score 3):

1) Turn on compression at the beginning of your script:

```
SET mapred.output.compress 'true';
SET mapred.output.compression.codec 'org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec';
```

2) Store the data.

```
STORE DATA INTO 'path_to_file’ USING JsonStorage();
```

The resulting files in the directory should be bz2-compressed.

Answer (score -1):

JsonStorage doesn't support compression, but you can write your own implementation that does: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#load-store-functions

Comment: the answer from Feb 26 '14 at 13:17, by fred [1005805], works!